# Determine method parameter's context

Tags: c#, reflection, parameters, stack-trace

Here's a challenging one.  Is it possible, using any method whatsoever, to implicitly determine the name of the property that is passed as a parameter to a method?

(This may at first appearance seem like a duplicate of another question, but there is a subtle but important different insofar that we are always working with properties, which is key).

Here is the example scenario:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    public void SomeStrangeMethod()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo() { Bar = "Hello" };
        string result = FindContext(foo.Bar);  // should return "Bar"
    }

    public string FindContext(object obj)
    {
        // TODO? - figure out the property name corresponding to the passed parameter.  
        // In this example, we need to somehow figure out that the value of "obj"
        // is the value of the property foo.Bar, and return "Bar"            
    }
```

Assume that from within FindContext, the passed parameter will always be a property of an object.  The catch is, we don't know what object.

Obviously, the problem can be easily solved by passing a second parameter that provides the missing context, i.e...

```
FindContext(foo, foo.Bar);    
FindContext("Bar", foo.Bar);
```

....but that's not what I want.  I want to be able to pass a single parameter and determine the property name represented by the value.

I understand that when the parameter is passed, the method context for FindContext does not contain sufficient information to determine this.  However, using some sleight of hand around stack traces and IL, perhaps we can still do it.  The reason why I think this must be possible is:

1. It is a requirement that the parameter passed to FindContext must always be a property of another object, and we know that it is possible to get said property names using reflection.
2. Using the StackTrace, we can get the calling context.
3. Out of the calling context, we should be able to somehow locate the symbol being used.
4. From that symbol, we should either be able to retrieve the property name, and/or the calling object's type, which via (1) we should be able to transform into the property of the calling object.

Does anybody know how to do this?  Note: This question is difficult, but I do not believe it is impossible.  I will not accept any answers of "impossible" unless someone can demonstrate why it is impossible.

Comment: Is `FindContext<Foo>(foo.Bar)` valid?

Comment: That's a brilliant suggestion.  It would seem possible, but then in the event that more than one property of Foo had the same value, there would be no way via reflection to determine which property was actually passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a lambda expression you can

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public void SomeStrangeMethod()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo() { Bar = "Hello" };
    string result = GetName(()=>foo.Bar);  // should return "Bar"
    Debug.WriteLine(result); // "Bar"
}


public static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    return ExtractPropertyName(expression);
}

/// <summary>
/// Extracts the name of a property from a suitable LambdaExpression.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="propertyExpression">The property expression.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ExtractPropertyName(LambdaExpression propertyExpression)
{
    if (propertyExpression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");
    }

    var memberExpression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(@"Not a member expression", "propertyExpression");
    }

    var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (property == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(@"Not a property", "propertyExpression");
    }

    var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);
    if (getMethod.IsStatic)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(@"Can't be static", "propertyExpression");
    }

    return memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) uses C#'s expression trees sugar support passing "properties" for the purpose of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanging` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`. For details, see [ObservableObject.cs](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/cf8d07c2ec3f#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight (NET35)/ObservableObject.cs)

```
void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        var propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertyExpression);
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The calling code can then use this:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Property);
```

Instead of relying on hard-coded strings like this:

```
RaisePropertyChanged("Property");
```

Answer (score 1):

No - this is not always possible.

```
3. Out of the calling context, we should be able to somehow locate the symbol being used.
```

This is the part that fails.  You can't get, at runtime, the symbol being used for the method parameter (at least not directly).  There are no tools in the Reflection library which provide this type of analysis or metadata.

That being said, this would, potentially, be possible with a lot of IL analysis.  If you used a tool like [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to decompile the assembly, find the "calling context", and then examine the IL for the call to the method in question.

Comment: That may be an option.  I'm thinking along the lines of MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray();  I'm not an IL master, but perhaps since there is a single parameter with a single property, there would be a consistent offset in the IL where one could determine this at runtime - 
    i.e. MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray()[2] // 2 is always the IL offset of the property passed...???

Comment: @DanMcCann You'd have to examine the caller's IL, not yours.  You'd always be getting a copy of the property, so the parameter passed in would be a "simple" type and have no relation to the containing object.  Say Foo.Bar was an int, you'd just be getting an (unnammed) int value, with no idea whether it was contained within an object, a local, etc.

Comment: Correct, but you can get the caller's IL through StackFrame.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to find out property name from an `Expression` without explicitly specifying the object type in the `Expression` you'll need an extension method:

```
public static class ObjectExt
{
    public static string FindContext<T,TProp>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T,TProp>> expression) {
        return ( expression.Body as MemberExpression ).Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Then if we place it in your code sample

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public void SomeStrangeMethod()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo() { Bar = "Hello" };
    string result = foo.FindContext(s => s.Bar);  // should return "Bar"
}
```